# freeswitch v1.6 use speex codec error

Tags: freeswitch

I have compiled freeswitch from branch v1.6 sourcecode ,when i use speex codec , freeswitch console :

2016-05-09 15:37:31.611965 [WARNING] switch_core_codec.c:721 Codec SPEEX Exists but not at the desired implementation. 16000hz 64ms 1ch
2016-05-09 15:37:31.611965 [ERR] switch_core_media.c:3025 Can't load codec?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to the problem is here: "16000hz **64ms** 1ch". If you look at the FreeSWITCH configuration file `vars.xml`, you will see many examples of ptimes like this one:

`DVI4@16000h@40i  - IMA ADPCM 16kHz using 40ms ptime. (multiples of 10)`

So FreeSWITCH is probably complaining about that 64ms packet time, as it's not a multiple of 10. You should be able to change that in the codec preferences on your endpoint configuration.